# Google Play Integrity Quota Increase

Tags: google-play-integrity-api

Google Play Integrity Quota Increase

How are you calling the Play Integrity API?
My app is calling the API directly

How often will you call the API for each user?
Once per 15 min

Is there any PII or SPII used for the nonce (e.g. user id, user name, phone number, Android ID, SSN, etc)?
Yes, but hashed or encrypted

How are you validating Play Integrity API responses?
Server side - by calling Play’s server to decrypt and verify

How does your app retry in case of Play Integrity API errors?
Retry with exponential backoff

How will your app act when the Play Integrity API detects risky traffic?
Deny access to functionality (for example, users won’t be able to log-in). I want unauthorized usage of my app to go down.

Quota request - Estimated total queries per day
1,000,000 to 10,000,000 (1M to 10M)

Rejected 4 Times - Unable to understand what is going wrong here.

Reason - We’re unable to fulfill your request for Consumer Project ID “551385724102” for the requested 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 (1M to 10M) queries per day as we have identified that your method of validating Play Integrity API responses is incorrect.

Any suggestion or anything that i'm doing wrong here..

Reference Form - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/piaqr

Read the documentation, yet was unable to find the correct way. In many places, it did mention that it is decrypted by google managed service but on selecting this as an option, it was marked as incorrect. Bit confused..

Answer (score 0):

Please check what do you sent on the server side as a packageName

```
// Example in Java but applies for all Play Integrity server requests
playIntegrity.v1()
.decodeIntegrityToken("YourPackageNameHere", integrityRequestToken)                
.execute();
```

If the packageName is wrong (too often?) Google will deny your request.

Edit:
15 minutes is a really short time tbh.
You should only do Play Integrity requests before operations that require a high level of security.
Google might also deny your request because they think you overuse the API.